# VBScript Loop Counter

Tags: loops, vbscript, count, counter

I need a loop counter that starts at 001 and continues until the scripts reaches the end of the recordset.
The counter needs to be displayed as:

```
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
011
012
013
```

etc...

It needs to be a fixed length of three characters and the number will never exceed 999.

Everytime I try this the counter ignores the zeros at the start and just counts like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

etc...

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably an easier way to do this, but here is what I would do:

```
for i = 1 to 999
    if i > 99 then
        wscript.echo i
    elseif i > 9 then
        wscript.echo "0" & i
    else
        wscript.echo "00" & i
    end if
next
```

Comment: Thanks, I've basically done the same as your suggestion and it works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Or:

```
>> For Each i In Array(0, 1, 9, 11, 88, 101)
>>     WScript.Echo Right(1000 + i, 3)
>> Next
>>
000
001
009
011
088
101
>>
```